# How can I remove multiple ticks from a dog quickly?

Tags: dogs, parasites, ticks

There's a female stray dog in my area who was recently spayed and as being spayed in a poor Indian government hospital she's got ticks all over her body.

Manual removal of the ticks is not possible because she won't sit still for long, and I can't give her a bath for a month as she was spayed recently.

Is any spray which will help to get rid of ticks? And also is there any natural anti-tick stuff?

Answer (score 3):

Manual removal is best, because it also allows you to clean/disinfect the wounds with [isopropyl alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol) (or other disinfectant). If she doesn't sit still for you to remove all of the ticks at once, you can try just pulling off one or two at a time, then giving her a break (petting her, giving her treats, playing a game, etc) before pulling off another tick or two.

You can use some sprays or medications (many of them are found in [these charts](http://www.drsfostersmith.com/pic/article.cfm?aid=325)), but they can be dangerous if the dog is exposed to them multiple times in a single month. For example, if you treat her and then tomorrow your neighbor treats her because your neighbor didn't know that you already sprayed her. She may get an overdose and become very ill. You should read the directions and make sure that the product that you chose can be applied frequently without any danger.