# My dog has got ticks inside her ears

Tags: dogs, parasites, ticks

What happened with me is very similar to [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/how-can-i-remove-multiple-ticks-from-a-dog-quickly). My dog too got spayed in an Indian Government Hospital and now has ticks all over her body. That is not very troubling since ticks on the body can be removed easily but the big problem is that some ticks have found their way into the poor dogs ear which is very scary. I am currently unable to do anything about it because I am scared I might disturb her ear in some irreparable way.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have access to a veterinarian to remove the ticks or are not able to remove them yourself I would suggest getting a veterinary approved tick preventative:

- Bravecto
- Advantix
- Nexgard

Keep in mind once the ticks are done feasting they will fall off on their own, your dog will most likely shake them out as they have a hard time moving once engorged.

8 weeks post bite you will need to run a blood test to rule out tick-borne diseases such as [Lyme](https://www.cdc.gov/lyme/), [Ehrlichia spp.](https://www.cdc.gov/ehrlichiosis/symptoms/index.html) and [anaplasmosis spp.](https://www.cdc.gov/anaplasmosis/symptoms/index.html) The test we run yearly on our pets in North America is the [4DX](https://www.idexx.com/small-animal-health/products-and-services/snap-4dx-plus-test.html), it may be different in India.

In the future it is best to Keep your dog on tick prevention during the tick seasons to prevent you and your pet from getting bit.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would recommend a Flea & Tick pill like [Bravecto](https://us.bravecto.com/for-dogs.aspx).

This way the ticks will die without disturbing your dog's ear.

Comment: Flea and tick treatments are preventive, Your recommended product takes up to 12 hours to kill existing ticks. Optimally you want the ticks of much faster then that.  [Your goal is to remove the tick as quickly as possible–not waiting for it to detach (or die)](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17598/tick-removal-to-twist-or-not-twist/17600#17600)

Comment: I agree with you @James, but in this case the ticks are inside dog's ear. Apparently, it's not possible to remove them manually.

Comment: I found this pdf 'Do Tick Attachment Times Vary between Different Tick-Pathogen Systems' www.mdpi.com/2076-3298/4/2/37/pdf that shows many diseases can be transmitted by ticks in less then the 12 hours it takes for the pill to work.